# How to access a certain jQuery extend function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is code for a slideshow plugin I am using. I am trying to jump to specific slides based on the button that is pressed.

How do I access the 'jump' function with an argument of '2'?

```
$.extend( $.fn.cycletwo, c2 );

$.extend( c2.API, {
next: function() {
    var opts = this.opts();
    if ( opts.busy && ! opts.manualTrump )
        return;

    var count = opts.reverse ? -1 : 1;
    if ( opts.allowWrap === false && ( opts.currSlide + count ) >= opts.slideCount )
        return;

    opts.API.advanceSlide( count );
    opts.API.trigger('cycletwo-next', [ opts ]).log('cycletwo-next');
},

jump: function( index ) {
    // go to the requested slide
    var fwd;
    var opts = this.opts();
    if ( opts.busy && ! opts.manualTrump )
        return;
    var num = parseInt( index, 10 );
    if (isNaN(num) || num < 0 || num >= opts.slides.length) {
        opts.API.log('goto: invalid slide index: ' + num);
        return;
    }
    if (num == opts.currSlide) {
        opts.API.log('goto: skipping, already on slide', num);
        return;
    }
    opts.nextSlide = num;
    clearTimeout(opts.timeoutId);
    opts.timeoutId = 0;
    opts.API.log('goto: ', num, ' (zero-index)');
    fwd = opts.currSlide < opts.nextSlide;
    opts.API.prepareTx( true, fwd );
},

opts.API.updateView();
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jump is a key and this function is a value for jump
 the **jump** key is contract in the object such as **slide** that you can access to that 
for example : slide.jump()

Comment: It's the $.extend that is throwing me off.
The page of concern is [here](http://www.dolphinent.com/wp/products).

Answer (score 0):

Say `slide` is the wrapped DOM object returned by $(...), then you can try

```
slide.cycletwo.API.jump(2);
```

Or why not find it out using browser's `developer tools > Console`